# Hacer que se cierre un menú tocando en cualquier sitio

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive

Estoy en un proyecto de una landing page. Hice un menú con CSS con un label e input, y que al tener el checked se muestre el menú desplazándose ya que está oculto.
Además, con jquery hice una función que cuando el label tenga el click, el body tenga `overflow:hidden` para que no se pueda hacer scroll, y también hice una especie de overlay oscuro que tapa todo el contenido y resalta el menú (esto usando la clase en común que tiene tanto el label de abrir como el de cerrar).
Quiero, que, cuando se toque el *overlay*, también se vaya el menú.

```js
//JQUERY EFFECTS
$(".btn-Bars").click(function() {
  $("body").toggleClass("hidden");
  $(".content-web").toggleClass("overlay");
});
```

```css
.header-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}

#btnMenu {
  display: none;
}

.nav-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #44a100;
}

.btn-Bars {
  font-size: 2.2em;
  margin-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-Menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  left: -50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.btn-Times {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 42%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

#btnMenu:checked~.nav-Menu {
  left: 0%;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="body">
  <div class="content-web">
    <header class="header">
      <div class="content content-flex">
        <div class="header-nav">
          <div class="nav-content">
            <input type="checkbox" id="btnMenu">
            <label class="btn-Bars btn-Open" for="btnMenu"><i class="fal fa-bars"></i></label>
            <img class="logo" src="https://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/click-here-button.jpg" alt="">
            <nav class="nav-Menu">
              <label class="btn-Times btn-Bars" for="btnMenu"><i class="fal fa-times"></i></label>
              <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="">INICIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="">INFORMACI&Oacute;N</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACTO</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="social-menu">
                <li class="facebook"><a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                <li class="instagram"><a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <!-- TERMINA NAV-CONTENT -->
        </div>
        <!-- TERMINA HEADER NAV -->
        <div class="header-contact">
          <div class="contact-container">
            <div class="contact-col col-novisible"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> 097 232 232</div>
            <div class="contact-col col-novisible"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> tucorreo@mail.com</div>
            <div class="contact-col col-visible"><i class="fad fa-calendar-check"></i> AGEND&Aacute; TU CONSULTA EN L&Iacute;NEA</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- TERMINA CONTENT FLEX -->
    </header>

    <main class="main" id="main">
    </main>
  </div>
  <!-- TERMINA WEB CONTENT -->
```

CÓDIGO JS:

```
    <script>
    $(".openMenu").click(function(){
        $("body").toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".content-web").toggleClass("overlay");
    });
</script>
```

Código CSS:

```
    .hidden{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
}

.overlay::before{
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%;
    top:0; 
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Lo que yo te recomendaría es trabajar con una clase `active` en css y solo cuando el elemento tenga esa clase muestras tu menu:

```
.menu.active {
  right: 0%;
}
```

2.- Estamos diciendo que solo cuando el elemento con la clase **menu** tenga una clase **active** el margen derecho sera 0%

3.- Entonces esta clase puedes jugarla con JavaScript En este caso con jQuery

4.- Te dejo un ejemplo practico que te ayudará a entenderlo mejor

5.- El codigo esta comentado para que puedas entenderlo.

```js
//ACCEDEMOS AL BOTON Y LE AGREGAMOS EL EVENTO CLICK 

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  //AL ELEMENTO QUE TIENE LA CLASE MENU LE AGREGAMOS LA CLASE ACTIVE
  document.querySelector(".menu").classList.add("active");


   //PARA QUE FUNCINONE EL OVERLAY NECESITAS AGREGAR LA CLASE OVERLAY A CONTENT-WEB
 document.querySelector(".content-web").classList.add("overlay");


});

//AGREGAMOS UN EVENTO DE TIPO CLICK A TODO EL DOCUMENTO
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

//DECIMOS QUE SI DONDE SE DIO CLICK NO TIENE LA CASE MENU OCULTAMOS EL MENU
  if (!e.target.classList.contains("menu")) {
    document.querySelector(".menu").classList.remove("active");

//REMOVEMOS LA CLASE OVERLAY PARA QUE SE OCULTE
 document.querySelector(".content-web").classList.remove("overlay");

  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.menu.active {
  right: 0%;
}
```

```html
<button>Mostrar Menu</button></nav>
   
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>ABOUT US</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
        <li>SUPPORT</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Me funcionó perfectamente, el único tema es que el overlay ya no funciona correctamente, ¿podrías ayudarme en eso? Actualizé la pregunta para que puedas ver el código

Comment: Hay alguna manera de poder ver tu proyecto en produccion ?? Considera https://codepen.io/pen/ me compartes el enlace de tu proyecto, para poder realizar pruebas en el.

Comment: Okey, hago eso y te adjunto el link

Comment: https://codepen.io/ByFaabri/pen/eYzBzVW

Comment: Perfecto estoy editando mi respuesta  para que funcione el overlay

Comment: @Fabricio Listo añadi las 2 lineas de codigo para que el overlay funcione correctamente.

Comment: Nikola, me olvidé de mencionarte que estuve intentando toda la noche y me funcionó con lo que probé, lamento no haberte dicho y haberte hecho perder tiempo. Tomé tu código como base y solo añadí dos líneas de codigo con el addClass y el removeClass.